# Is it a good practice to add 50 buttons programmatically in android?

Tags: android, performance, textview, android-linearlayout

I am just testing some stuff out. I wanted to know is it a good practice to add 50 or more Buttons, using a for loop, in a linear layout? and is it a good practice to use OnClickListeners on it? The code lags after I add 80+ Buttons. I tried to use the technique of Recyclerview to load only visible views but It still lags and formatting gets lost too.

Activity:

```
public class ButtonsTest extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
final ArrayList<Button> Buttons = new ArrayList<>();
//I want this text to be at least 800-1500 words.
String DemoText = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.buttonstext);
    FlowLayout fl = (FlowLayout) findViewById(R.id.layouttest);
    List<String> t = Arrays.asList(DemoText.split(" "));

    for (int x = 0; x < t.size(); x++) {
        Buttons.add(new Button(this));
        Buttons.get(x).setText(t.get(x));
        Buttons.get(x).setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        Buttons.get(x).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        Buttons.get(x).setId(x);
        Buttons.get(x).setOnClickListener(this);
        fl.addView(Buttons.get(x));
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Button t = (Button) v;
    t.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
    t.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
}
}
```

XML code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <org.apmem.tools.layouts.FlowLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/layouttest"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </org.apmem.tools.layouts.FlowLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: A "yes" or "no" answer to this question doesn't really help you solve your *actual* problem. If you showed your code and asked "how to fix this so that it doesn't lag?" you'd solve your problem much faster.

Comment: I've added my code. Can you help out now? Thanks :)

Comment: It depends on when you want those buttons to be displayed. Are they all visible at the same time? Then use GridLayout / RelativeLayout or even RecyclerView, doesn't matter, though a GridLayout will make your life easier. If they are not visible all at the same time and there's some scrolling involved, use ListView / GridView or RecyclerView.

Answer (score 1):

Let me be the one to say **no**. If you're going to need so many buttons, specially inside a scrollview, they should instead be held inside some sort of container that recycles the views. A `RecyclerView` ideally, where you specify the data, and create the relationship between that data and the views, that will in turn be created programmatically.

So **yes** but just not in a loop and adding them like that

---

#### Some useful links

- [Creating Lists and Cards example](http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html)
- [RecyclerView documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html)

Comment: I tried using RecyclerView but I want it to be Horizontal and should function like a FlowLayout. The best approach I could think of is by adding this. Would you guide me it there is any other way to solve this? 
thanks

Comment: RecyclerView doesn't enforce the way you display the views and if by flowlayout you mean that adding a new button adds it to the right of the previous one until it doesn't fit, then goes to the next line, you should look into https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout

Comment: I'm using this but I guess a layout won't help. I need a layout manager or something.
Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a good practice to add them programmatically but I would consider using a `ListView` or `RecyclerView`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make something like a grid of minesweeper with onclick listener on each button then use either relative layout technique or grid layout in android using  java file and resize the button with layoutParams property.
I have done this and adding 90-150 button is smooth.
I Can give you my implementation if this helps.

Comment: I'm trying to fill up one line with view and when space is finished I want it to flow to next line. A recyclerview cannot do that nor can a ListView

Comment: A RecyclerView *can* do that. You just need the right `LayoutManager` that gives you the desired behaviour. Chances are someone has already open sourced a layout manager that does what you need.

Comment: Try this with relative layout. First design a button then start inserting buttons after previous inserted button in the same row. when the row is filled then just increase the column count to insert button below the previous row. You can always get the width of device  with display.width and set it as row width

Comment: @sachin I'll try that out. Hope it helps :)
Thanks for help